# Custom word styling from csv into InDesign

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, basil.js

I have a builded a text editor in javascript that takes keyboard-written-text as an input, and outputs the same paragraph, but with each word styled accordingly to how it was written. My text editor exports a CSV file, where each row is a word, and its specifc styling values covering: font size, word tracking, spacing between two words, and the color of the word.

[The effect can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYD5U.png)

Now I want to import this csv file into InDesign using the [basil.js](http://basiljs.ch) library, so that I can create a text box with a paragraph of the words and the stylings located in the csv file.

The csv file can be seen here:

```
word,spacing,size,tracking,color
"Hello,",0,16,0,90
this,70,16,0.22,90
is,0,16,7,0
a,0,16,0,90
test,0,24,3.98,90
to,0,16,5.06,90
show,0,16,-1.56,90
what,42.84,16,-0.6,90
i,0,16,0,90
mean,0,16,-0.79,90
```

I’ve managed to import the csv, create a paragraph with each word, and make the font-size styling work for each work. But I can’t make the tracking property work. Also I dont really have an Idea how to create increasd space between two words in a paragraph through basil.js (In the texteditor it used left-padding css). Also I dont know how to change the color of each word.

Is this possible with basil.js?

My current code looks like this:

```
#includepath "~/Documents/;%USERPROFILE%Documents";
#include "basiljs/bundle/basil.js";


function draw(){

   b.clear(b.doc());

   //import csv file
   var data = b.CSV.decode( b.loadString("mycsv.csv"));

   //paragraph placeholder
   var paragraph = ""; 

   //parse to right data type,
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     data[i].spacing = parseInt(data[i].spacing);
     data[i].size = parseInt(data[i].size);
     data[i].tracking = parseInt(data[i].tracking);
     data[i].color = parseInt(data[i].color);
     // data[i].word is already a string at it should

     //Add each word in the csv row to create a paragraph
     paragraph +=  data[i].word + " ";
  };

      //create a textframe element for the paragraph   
      var tf = b.text(paragraph, 36, 36, 500, b.height);
      var myWords = b.words(tf);

      // iterate through each word and  apply the specific styling for the
      specific word. 

      for(var i = 0; i < myWords.length; i++){  

             var size_ =  data[i].size; // font size
             var tracking_ = data[i].tracking; //word tracking
             var color_ = data[i].color;    // font color 
             var spacing_ = data[i].spacing;

            // this one works
            myWords[i].pointSize = size_; 

            //I'ld like to change tracking for each word - but this dosnt work
            myWords[i].tracking = tracking_; 

           //myWords[i].color = rgb(color_); - How can I apply a specific color to a specific word in the paragraph
           // myWords[i].word_spacing =  - I would like to increase the spacing between specific pairs of words. How can this be done?   

       }
}

b.go();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Tracking

I think your tracking does actually work, but the values you get from your csv are way too small to be noticeable. Legal tracking values range from `-1000` up to `10000`, so I would multiply your values by 100 or by 1000 to see the effect.

#### Color

To change the color of a word, you need to change its `fillColor` property. To create a valid InDesign color you can make use of the basil function `b.color(r, g, b)`. So to color a word in red, you could do

```
myWords[i].fillColor = b.color(255, 0, 0);
```

#### Word space

To change the space between to words, you actually need to target the space string between two words and change its `kerningValue` property. To do that you can separate the text in all its characters using `b.characters(text)`, like you already did with the words. Then you need to loop through the characters and see if it is a space and if so, you can change its kerning value.

```
var chars = b.characters(tf);

for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  if(chars[i].contents === " ") {
    chars[i].kerningValue = 400;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx mdomino, that fixed all my issues :D